# Crash in AlertDialog builder when android support library updated to 24

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-alertdialog

The code was working fine before, but when I updated support library to 24, It crashes when displaying alert dialog. 
Couldn't find any help as it is updated recently.

Code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle;
builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
//set buttons and title code
builderSingle.show();
```

Logcat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.internal.widget.DialogTitle" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.abc-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.abc-2/lib/arm, /data/app/com.abc-2/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:583)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.setContentView(AppCompatDialog.java:80) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:214) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:257) 
     at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:394) 
     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:295) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:953) 
     at qi.mnav.search.fragments.RecentsFavouriteFragment.handleFavLongClick(RecentsFavouriteFragment.java:525) 
     at qi.mnav.search.fragments.RecentsFavouriteFragment.onItemLongClick(RecentsFavouriteFragment.java:353) 
     at android.widget.AbsListView.performLongPress(AbsListView.java:3134) 
     at android.widget.AbsListView$CheckForLongPress.run(AbsListView.java:3066) 
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.internal.widget.DialogTitle
     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 31 more
```

And the support libraries are:

```
    compile('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile('com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0') {
        force = true
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
```

Comment: compileSdkVersion has to be 24 and **all your support libraries have to be of same version** 24.0.0. Do a clean build. Disable Instant Run.

Comment: @EugenPechanec thanks for your reply. I changed the compileSdkVersion and buildToolVersion to 24, but its still crashing and the log is also same..

Comment: @priyanka that with clean build + instant run disabled has no affect either?

Comment: Enable multidex. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html What device does this happen on? Please post your build.gradle file.

Comment: @Sufian no, clean build is also not helping. Instant run is also disabled.

Comment: @EugenPechanec multidex is enabed. Have updated the question with build.gradle

Comment: I am using Motorola G 2nd Gen with Android 6.0

Comment: import for dialog is
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;

Comment: Are you having any import called `android.support.v7.internal.widget.DialogTitle`?? In you any class ??

Comment: That was really a good catch..thankx so much. I was trying it since last 2 days. I changed the import to: android.app.AlertDialog; and its working fine! Thanks!

Comment: should i post that as a answer so that others will also get solution same like you ??

Comment: Yea sure please do that. I was about to suggest that.

Comment: @priyanka posted :) You can edit it if you wish

Comment: @priyanka the solution fixes the problem, but I think it will make the Material theme disappear from your dialogs. I guess you still should report the issue at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list so this bug gets fixed.

Comment: @Sufian you are right. Now the dialog is looking a little ugly! :(

Comment: have added to issue here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=215765

Comment: @priyanka starred. If you can create a sample project for it (and attach it on that issue thread), it would help the dev team to act quicker. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think there is some problem with your imports.**

The Exception :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.internal.widget.DialogTitle"
```

says it is unable to find `DialogTitle` but i am not seeing `DialogTitle` any where in your code.

So if you are having any import called `android.support.v7.internal.widget.DialogTitle` any where in your project then remove it.

You need to import this for your AlertDialog:

```
 import android.app.AlertDialog;
```

instead of this:

```
 import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
```

Answer (score 0):

Import this:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
```

Comment: How does it add anything new to the already posting comments/answers?