# App crashes on AlertDialog .show() - I've found solution

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm new here. 
I'm building an app but whenever it comes to the AlertDialog .show() it chrashes. I've researched all over the internet but couldn't find any solution. Most of the cases I've found got their problem fixed by changing 'Context'  on
AlertDialog.Builder example = new AlertDialog.Builder(Context) 
to
AlertDialog.Builder example = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);

But that's not my case, I've beeing using MyActivity.this all long and still crashes.

Here's my code:

ublic class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Button btMudaTela;

final Funcoes funcao = new Funcoes();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btMudaTela = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btMudaTela);

    //Ao clicar no botão outra activity será aberta (ActivityCadastro)
    btMudaTela.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            adb.setTitle("teste");
            adb.setMessage("ok");
            adb.create().show();
            funcao.mudaActivity(MainActivity.this, ActivityCadastro.class);
            finish();
        }
    });

}
```

}

And here's log from Logcat on my device:

```
06-23 07:41:42.113  3303  3303 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.teste.projetofinal, PID: 3303

06-23 07:41:42.113  3303  3303 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.example.teste.projetofinal.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:46)

06-23 07:41:42.123   954  1367 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.teste.projetofinal/.MainActivity

06-23 07:41:43.334   954  1602 I ActivityManager: Process com.example.teste.projetofinal (pid 3303) (adj 9) has died.

06-23 07:41:43.334   954  1454 I WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{444ca450 u0 com.example.teste.projetofinal/com.example.teste.projetofinal.MainActivity}

06-23 07:50:39.406  6806  6806 W InstallAppProgress: Replacing package:com.example.teste.projetofinal

06-23 07:50:42.219  5389  5389 I Finsky  : [1] com.google.android.finsky.verifier.impl.br.c(104): Verification complete: id=0, package_name=com.example.teste.projetofinal

06-23 07:50:42.960   954  1046 I PackageManager: Package com.example.teste.projetofinal codePath changed from /data/app/com.example.teste.projetofinal-19.apk to /data/app/com.example.teste.projetofinal-20.apk; Retaining data and using new

06-23 07:50:43.921   954  1046 W PackageManager: Code path for pkg : com.example.teste.projetofinal changing from /data/app/com.example.teste.projetofinal-19.apk to /data/app/com.example.teste.projetofinal-20.apk

06-23 07:50:43.921   954  1046 W PackageManager: Resource path for pkg : com.example.teste.projetofinal changing from /data/app/com.example.teste.projetofinal-19.apk to /data/app/com.example.teste.projetofinal-20.apk

06-23 07:50:45.592   954  1036 I CrashAnrDetector: onPackageUpdateFinished : com.example.teste.projetofinal

06-23 07:50:46.073  6987  6987 E dalvikvm: >>>>> com.example.teste.projetofinal [ userId:0 | appId:10200 ]

06-23 07:50:47.444  6987  6987 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.teste.projetofinal, PID: 6987

06-23 07:50:47.444  6987  6987 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.example.teste.projetofinal.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:40)

06-23 07:50:47.444   954  1602 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.teste.projetofinal/.MainActivity

06-23 07:50:48.806   954  1602 I WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{433e3670 u0 com.example.teste.projetofinal/com.example.teste.projetofinal.MainActivity}

06-23 07:50:48.836   954  1545 I ActivityManager: Process com.example.teste.projetofinal (pid 6987) (adj 9) has died.

06-23 07:50:51.188  3939  3939 E SPPClientService: [PackageInfoChangeReceiver] [handlePkgRemovedEvent] PackageName : com.example.teste.projetofinal, true, false

06-23 07:50:54.531  5389  5389 I Finsky  : [1] com.google.android.finsky.externalreferrer.d.run(9): Package state data is missing for com.example.teste.projetofinal

06-23 07:50:55.792  3498  7271 I FontsPackageChangeOp: Package com.example.teste.projetofinal has no metadata
```

Yeah!!!! After 2 days of digging on the Internet I finally found solution here:
[Crash in AlertDialog builder when android suport library updated to 24](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38308057/crash-in-alertdialog-builder-when-android-suport-library-updated-to-24)

You need to import this for your AlertDialog:

```
 import android.app.AlertDialog;
```

instead of this:

```
 import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
```

Comment: Please add the exception and stack trace you are receiving.

Comment: I've changed my code to my MainActivity (same project) because it is easier to read and also because the problem is the same. Line 40 is line adb.create().show(); The same happens if it's adb.show();
I also added Logcat that's running on my device.

Comment: you saved me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without your stacktrace it is a little difficult to figure out the problem exactly, but, I would guess it is related to your builder.

You have this line:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alerta = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityCadastro.this);
```

You then set various fields on the object. Near the end, you call

```
alerta.show()
```

The problem is, this is not an alert dialog you are calling it on, this is a builder object. To fix this, you need to actually create the alert dialog object by calling build on the builder; just change the code to the following:

```
alerta.create().show();
```

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html

Let me know if that fixes it.

-Sil

Comment: Thank you very much for your response!
I've changed my code to my MainActivity (same project) because it is easier to read and also because the problem is the same. I did like you said, changing Line 40 to adb.create().show() instead of adb.show() but  The same still happen :(
I also added Logcat that's running on my device.

Answer (score 0):

Use simply

```
adb.show();
```

instead of

```
adb.create().show();
```